# How to Update an item in a from a Generic collection/ObservableCollection

Tags: generics, collections

I have a generic collection, in this case it is an ObservableCollection, having a method to Update a an Item, which it could be generic.

Any ideas? The collection is called _Data

```
    private ObservableCollection<T> _data;
    public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good work around, not very clean but it will do the job.

```
   public void Update(bool saveImmediately, params T[] items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {                
            _data.RemoveAt(_data.IndexOf(item));
            _data.Add(item);
        }
    }
```